# Laravel 5.4 search query for multiple checkbox values

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm new to checkboxes. I want to let users do a search based on three possible filters represented by checkbox lists.
    users can search different way.
        please help me.
            [Here is my Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ7af.png)

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'search-job']) !!}
<p>
    Hours:
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobs_type[]" value="Part Time">Part Time
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobs_type[]" value="Full Time">Full Time
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobs_type[]" value="Temporary">Temporary
</p>

<p>
    category:
    <br/>

    @foreach($job_function as $job_category)
    <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="job_function[]" value="{{ $job_category->id }}">{{$job_category->name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach

</p>

<p>
    salary
    <br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="salary[]" value="1000"/> upto $1000<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="salary[]" value="1000-1999">$1,000- 2,000<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="salary[]" value="2000-3999">$2,000 - 4,000<br/>
</p>

<input type="submit" value="Search">

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Do you want to search in your data table data corresponding to users clicks, if so then provide your data table structure, and what did you already tried in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function job_search(Request $request){


$builder = Job::query();
$term = Request::all();

if(!empty($term['job_function'])){
   $builder->whereIn('category_id',$term['job_function']);

}
if(!empty($term['jobs_type'])){
   $builder->orWhereIn('jobs_type',$term['jobs_type']);
}
if(!empty($term['salary'])){
    $builder->orWhereIn('salary','=',$term['salary']);
}

$result = $builder->orderBy('id')->get();

return view('frontend.pages.job.find_jobs')->withResult($result);
    }
```